# Access function inside class in global scope

Tags: php, oop

I would like to call my dump method in my Debug class in global scope.
Like this :

```
class Debug {
    ...
    function dump($var) {}
    ...
}

dump('toto');
```

So I would like to call dump everywhere but keep my class.

I don't want to do that if it's possible :

```
dump(var) {
    $debug = new Debug();
    $debug->dump(var);
}
```

Is there a way to export the method of my class?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: This is not how OOP works. You miss the basic idea behind encapsulation. Why do you implement a class if you want a global function?

Comment: Method already exist in vendor packages. And I was wondering if I could "export" globally one of this function

Comment: The idea behind OOP is to enclose internal code, so that it is _guaranteed_ not to be used from outside. That way the _internal_ implementation of a feature or detail is decoupled from the _external_ usage. Which means to internal implementation can be altered, modified, removed, whatever without the external usage being altered. There is no "export", since there is nothing to be exported. The internal method is an _internal_ detail. None of your business from the _external_ point if view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a static method if you just want to format the output for dumping it :

```
class Debug {
    ...
    static function dump($var) {}
    ...
}
```

and call it like:

```
Debug::dump('hola');
```

Using static method is not a recommended practice, though, if you don't have any dependency on your `Debug::debug()` method and you are gonna use just for formatting or logging the parameter, there is no problem to use it

**Updated**

Since `Debug` class is a vendor class you could use PHP DI container like Pimple https://pimple.symfony.com/ so after registering the `Debug` class as a service you call it everywhere, but you will need to inject it in all your classes which need debugging

If you don't want to use a container there is a dirty trick to extend the debug functionality with a static method, althouhg I wouldn't recommend it, I paste here the idea:

```
class Debug {
    function dump($var) {
        echo $var;
    }
}

class DebugExtended {
    static function myDump($var) {
        $debug = new Debug();
        $debug->dump($var);
    }
}

DebugExtended::myDump($debug);
```

Comment: thank for the answer but I can't rewrite the dump function. It is in vendor packages :/

Comment: I updated my post above after knowing you can't alter the vendor class